# How can deflector arrays block weapons fire?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

This question is based on this exchange from the TNG episode *The Outrageous Okona*

> Worf: "Captain, they are now locking lasers on us."
>
> Riker: "Lasers?"
>
> Worf: "Yes, sir."
>
> Picard: "Lasers can't even penetrate our navigation shields. Don't they know that?"

From my understanding, the navigational deflector is simply pushing objects out of the way in spaceflight.

Comment: The deflector is a mixture of shields and a long-range tractor.

Comment: Per the TNG technical manual shields work by curving space so it aims away from the ship.  How this doesn't cloak the ship is a mystery to me - but it would keep lasers away.

Comment: "How this doesn't cloak the ship is a mystery to me" because _plot_, @lucasbachmann. Because _plot_...

Comment: Because it's illegal for the Federation to cloak their ships and the Federation would *never* break the law.

Comment: I would honestly go with the description from other scifi that the shield absorb the energy of the laser and distribute it  through out the energy field.

Comment: Are "deflector arrays," "navigation shields," and "navigational deflector" all the same thing? Why call it three things in the question? It's a little confusing.  How can it block weapons? Picard said there are shields. I feel like I'm the only one not getting the question. (No VTC or DV, just ?)

Comment: The VTC because it's a REAL-WORLD SCIENCE QUESTION is hilarious to me. The question is worth existing for that laugh alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The '*Deflector*' is in fact several systems (various shields as well as repulsor beams) operating together to protect the ship from incoming particles including massive objects like micro-meteorites as well as normal sized particles such as atoms and, evidently, energetic photons.

[image]

> <sub><sup>[Star Trek: TNG Technical Manual](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation_Technical_Manual)</sup></sub>

This seems to include laser beams.